# Create a DataFrame from a JSON File

Tags: json, python-3.x, dataframe

I am trying to load a JSON file into a DataFrame, I know this question was answered multiple times but I've beein trying all the possible solutions but with no success, here is how my JSON file looks like:

```
{
"event": {
    "origin": "devicename",
    "module": "",
    "interface": "",
    "component": "",
    "payload": "{\"typeofsensor\" : \"US_distance\",\"distance\": 2}"
}}
{
"event": {
    "origin": "devicename",
    "module": "",
    "interface": "",
    "component": "",
    "payload": "{\"typeofsensor\" : \"mpu6050\",\"accelX\": 0.06, \"accelY\": 0.50, \"accelZ\": -0.88, \"temp\": 25.45}"
}}
```

---

What I am trying to do is to extract the information in the "payload" in order to create a DataFrame with columns are **typeofsensor** and **the sensor values** since I have diffrent types of sensors.

---

I tried:

```
data = []
for line in open('data.JSON', 'r'):
    data.append(json.loads(line))
```

I got this error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 1 (char 2)
```

---

I also tried:

```
df = pd.read_json('data.JSON', lines=True)
```

I got this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\DEVELO~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_204/911564313.py in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.read_json('data.JSON', lines=True)

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    205                 else:
    206                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 207             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    208 
    209         return cast(F, wrapper)

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310                 )
--> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    312 
    313         return wrapper

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py in read_json(path_or_buf, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates, keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit, encoding, encoding_errors, lines, chunksize, compression, nrows, storage_options)
    612 
    613     with json_reader:
--> 614         return json_reader.read()
    615 
    616 

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py in read(self)
    744                 data = ensure_str(self.data)
    745                 data_lines = data.split("\n")
--> 746                 obj = self._get_object_parser(self._combine_lines(data_lines))
    747         else:
    748             obj = self._get_object_parser(self.data)

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py in _get_object_parser(self, json)
    768         obj = None
    769         if typ == "frame":
--> 770             obj = FrameParser(json, **kwargs).parse()
    771 
    772         if typ == "series" or obj is None:

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py in parse(self)
    883 
    884         else:
--> 885             self._parse_no_numpy()
    886 
    887         if self.obj is None:

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py in _parse_no_numpy(self)
   1138         if orient == "columns":
   1139             self.obj = DataFrame(
-> 1140                 loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
   1141             )
   1142         elif orient == "split":

ValueError: Expected object or value
```

Comment: Please add the desired output and at least one of your many code attempts to the question and describe how your code attempt(s) failed to generate the desired output. If your code attempt raises an exception, please add the full traceback to the question.

Comment: This is not a valid json file

Comment: The problem with your input file is `duplicate keys` and `styling errors`, solve them and you've been all set to go :)

Comment: Spark will be able to read this JSON file as it treats each line as a separate JSON object. e.g `{...}\n{...}`

Comment: @TomRon Could you please explain more?

Comment: @meti I am trying to solve this problem but could you please provide me with useful links or documentations?

Comment: @tjheslin1 Could you please explain more?
thanks again

Comment: Put your file here and get the errors - https://jsonlint.com/
Generally, I would like to have a list of objects to the syntax should be something like - `[{"origin": "cccc", "module": 123 ...}, {"origin": "cff", "module": 456}]`

Comment: this is the Error:

`Error: Parse error on line 9:
...istance\": 2}" }} { "event": {  "ori
---------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'`
@TomRon

Comment: Yes, I should reformat the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your file into a valid format like below (eliminate `{}` from the middle and change key names to become unique):

```
{
    "event1": {
        "origin": "devicename",
        "module": "",
        "interface": "",
        "component": "",
        "payload": "{\"typeofsensor\" : \"US_distance\",\"distance\": 2}"
    },

    "event2": {
        "origin": "devicename",
        "module": "",
        "interface": "",
        "component": "",
        "payload": "{\"typeofsensor\" : \"mpu6050\",\"accelX\": 0.06, \"accelY\": 0.50, \"accelZ\": -0.88, \"temp\": 25.45}"
    }
}
```

easily read the file:

```
pd.read_json('path to/your_file.json')
#output
                                                   event1                                             event2
origin                                         devicename                                         devicename
module                                                                                                      
interface                                                                                                   
component                                                                                                   
payload    {"typeofsensor" : "US_distance","distance": 2}  {"typeofsensor" : "mpu6050","accelX": 0.06, "a...
```

Comment: This solution helps only if the JSON file is valid but the file that I have is really big and it's not possible to just modify it manually, is there any automated solution to fix the JSON file? @meti

Comment: The only solution that comes into my mind is to read the file and parse it into a valid format using python :), but I advise waiting to see anybody comes up with an automated solution.